# Why am i getting " Duplicate modifier for the type Test" and how to fix it

Tags: java, anagram

I was trying to make a method that returns true if given "Strings" are anagrams. unfortunately i cant even test it and i don know what is wrong. The markers at left says:

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Breakpoint:Test
>       - Duplicate modifier for the 
>        type Test

Here is the source code:

```
package zajecia19;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
public 
public class Test {
    public static boolean Anagraamy(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(s1.charAt(i))) {
                map.put(s1.charAt(i), map.get(s1.charAt(i)) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(s1.charAt(i), 1);
            }
            if (map.containsKey(s2.charAt(i))) {
                map.put(s2.charAt(i), map.get(s2.charAt(i)) - 1);
            } else {
                map.put(s2.charAt(i), -1);
            }
        }
        for( Integer value: map.values()){
            if(value != 0 ){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("slowa2"))) {
        System.out.println( Anagraamy("abba", "babb"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the extra `public` from your code.

Comment: One thing is very important when learning Java: trust the compiler. If it tells you about some "duplicate"; and gives you a line number; than turn to that line and see what is there; and maybe what is in the lines before. Besides: avoid writing lots of code before running the compiler. Always try to write only small chunks (of which you think: this should compile); then run the compiler; fix errors; if possible tun the code to test it. First writing 100 lines of code; to then start fixing errors makes the whole thing **much** harder for you!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because you have

```
public
public
```

there.

The obvious way to fix that: remove the first one. And next time: pay attention to what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: @SadiqAli Mainly on stack overflow, a bit on quora. Why are you asking?

Comment: Came across this and just imagined you shaking your head at the front of a class.

Comment: Honestly, I don't mind. The question is written up nicely and well formatted. Also polite. There are many questions from newbies that are much worse.